# launch bootstrap v5 modal from anchor tag inside a navbar

Tags: bootstrap-modal, anchor, bootstrap-5

I want to launch a bootstrap v5 modal from an anchor tag inside a navbar.
However, it doesn't work.
I have seen relative posts and I can't find the reason for this.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

This is My code:

```
       
<a class="nav-link px-3 contactperson" data-toggle="modal" href= "#contactModal"> Contact us</a> <!--here the modal is called-->
                         
<!--modal-->
<div id="contactModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <!-- aria-labelledby="#contactperson" -->
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Contact Us</h5>
                    <button type="button " class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <!--content-->
                    </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>'''

Thank you in advance
```

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `data-toggle` has become `data-bs-toggle` in Bootstrap 5.

So, replace:

```html
<a class="nav-link px-3 contactperson" data-toggle="modal" href= "#contactModal"> Contact us</a>
```

With:

```html
<a class="nav-link px-3 contactperson" data-bs-toggle="modal" href= "#contactModal"> Contact us</a>
```

Comment: You're welcome!